# Using .First() with IMobileServiceSyncTable?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I can't figure out how to return one item from an IMobileServiceSyncTable. I have queries like this that are really awkward since I'm building a list and then checking the contents whereas I just want to get the First item or FirstOrDefault to return null if it doesn't exist.

```
var itemId = await _someItemTable.Where (x => x.ItemId == itemId)
                                 .Select (x => x.OtherId)
                                 .Take (1)
                                 .ToListAsync ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `First` or `FirstOrDefault` on the awaited result:

```
var itemId = (await _someItemTable.Where (x => x.ItemId == itemId)
    .Select (x => x.OtherId)
    .Take (1)
    .ToEnumerableAsync ()).FirstOrDefault();
```